# Boolean variable not changing when it should

Tags: java, variables, boolean

I'm currently working on a homework assignment that illustrates the basics of OOP in Java. It's a very simple carwash simulation. I have two methods in the `Car` class, `isDirty` and `getDirty`. I have a `boolean` variable `Dirty` in the car class which is set to `false` because all 3 cars are supposed to start out clean. I'm supposed to check all 3 cars with the `isDirty` method to show that all 3 cars start out clean, after, I'm supposed to run the `getDirty` method to make the cars dirty and then run the `isDirty` method to show that the status changed from clean to dirty. For some reason the `boolean` variable `Dirty` isn't changing to true after running the `getDirty` method.

```
public class CarwashSimulation
{
  Carwash suds = new Carwash();
  Car carA = new Car();
  Car carB = new Car();
  Car carC = new Car();

  public void runSimulation()
  {
    System.out.println("Start Simulation");
    carA.isDirty();
    carB.isDirty();
    carC.isDirty();
    carA.getDirty();
    carB.getDirty();
    carC.getDirty();
    carA.isDirty();
    carB.isDirty();
    carC.isDirty();
  }
}



class Carwash
{
  public void washCar()
  {
    

  }

}

class Car
{
  boolean Dirty = false;

  public void getDirty()
  {
    boolean Dirty = true;
  }

  public boolean isDirty()
  {
    if (Dirty == true)
    {
      System.out.println("It's Dirty");
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      System.out.println("It's Clean");
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: in `getDirty()`, a new variable `boolean Dirty` is created and assigned the value `true`. However, what we want is to set the (existing) field `Dirty` to `true`. In order to achieve this, we only need to remove the `boolean`: `public void getDirty() { Dirty = true; }` --- Some remarks: - In java, field names should always start with a lowercase letter (`Dirty` -> `dirty`) - the prefix `get` is normally used for getters. I would suggest to rename `getDirty()` to something like `makeDirty()`.

Comment: Additionally to what was already said, I would advise you to look into the [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) and try to get used to it from the beginning. This will help yourself and everyone reading your code.

Comment: I apologize for yesterday, I didn't end up using any of the answers because I realized that I misread the instructions for the assignment so the question I asked was pointless from the start. So no, I don't intend on deleting this.

Comment: Java naming conventions have methods and variables start with a lower case letter. Also, getDirty() looks like a getter that would return the value of dirty. I would name it something like makeDirty().

Comment: @corn: deleting a question deprives *others* with a similar questions from finding the answers. Even if it turned out *you* didn't need the answers, some people have spent time and energy to write answers and it might still be useful to someone else. There are *very few* good reasons to delete questions that have answers.

Comment: Understood, I won't delete any further questions asked, it was an honest mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In method `getDirty()`, a new variable `boolean Dirty` is created and assigned the value `true`. However, what we want is to set the (existing) field `Dirty` to `true`. In order to achieve this, we only need to remove the `boolean`:

```
class Car {
    ...
    public void getDirty() {
        Dirty = true; 
    }
    ...
}
```

---

Some remarks on the code:

- In java, field names should always start with a lowercase letter (`Dirty` -> `dirty`)
- The prefix `get` in method names is normally used for getters. I would suggest to rename `getDirty()` to something like `makeDirty()` so that a user does not confuse it for a getter.

Answer (score 2):

`getDirty()` is not updating the data member, but declaring a local boolean that **hides** the data member, initializes it to `true` and then discards it when it goes out of scope. Remove the declaration, and you should be OK:

```
public void getDirty()
{
    Dirty = true; // Here!
}
```

**Side note:**
If this method is supposed to set the dirty state, `setDirty` is probably a better name for it.